# How do we move our electron app to show in second/external screen?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen, electron

My Electron app is showing the full screen on my first screen. Now how do I move it to my external screen also in full screen? I have tried the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> using the keyboard but it doesn't work in full screen.

And I want the Electron to open permanently in the second screen, so, What are the settings I have to make?

Comment: Are you asking for shortcuts from user perspective or how to move window to another screen from the code?